# Javascript - How to change animation's duration onclick

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

How can I change the animation duration onclick? This is what I've done, I created two buttons, one with an animationduration of 10s while the other has an animationduration of 20s. The duration regardless of which button I click is the same, 10 seconds, as it is in the class section. How can I get depending on the button I click two different durations? Please use normal Javascript, no Jquery. Thank you! I also need to use the document.GetElementById().classname =""; as it is in the code.

```js
function tenseconds() {
  animation();
  var sd = document.getElementById('ghost').className = 'earth';
  sd.style.animationDuration = "10s";
}

function twentyseconds() {
  animation();
  var sd = document.getElementById('ghost').className = 'earth';
  sd.style.animationDuration = "20s";
}

function animation() {
  document.getElementById('ghost').className = 'earth';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .earth {
      position: relative;
      animation: move 10s linear;
      background: red;
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes move {
      from {
        left: 0%;
      }
      to {
        left: 100%;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="ghost"> </div>
  <button onclick="tenseconds();">10 seconds </button>
  <button onclick="twentyseconds()"> 20 seconds </button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i suppose from what you are doing that you want to slow the animation and this is the wrong way ... check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48082314/how-to-slow-down-css-animation-on-hovering-element-without-jumps/48084423#48084423

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to use an animation, data attributes etc. Customize as needed. NOT supported in Edge, IE perhaps others.  Leave to you to investigate possible ways to fix that.  Review OLD edit for the original "fix"

I added another element and button so you could see how it might be used.

```js
var myAnimation = {
  keyframes: [
    // keyframes
    {
      transform: 'translateX(0px)'
    },
    {
      transform: 'translateX(300px)'
    }
  ],
  options: {
    // timing options
    // ms of duration default 1 second
    duration: 1000,
    iterations: 1, //forever would be Infinity
    easing: "linear"
  }
};

function animation(target, duration, visual) {
  let sd = document.getElementById(target);
  sd.className = visual;
  myAnimation.options.duration = duration * 1000;
  sd.animate(myAnimation.keyframes, myAnimation.options,visual);
}

function setup() {
  let classThings = document.getElementsByClassName("animate-button");

  let myFunction = function() {
    let duration = this.dataset.duration;
    let visual = this.dataset.visual;
    let target = this.dataset.target;
    animation(target, duration, visual);
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < classThings.length; i++) {
    classThings[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
  }
}
(function() {
  setup();
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .fire {
      position: relative;
      background: red;
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
    }
    
    .water {
      position: relative;
      background: blue;
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="ghost"></div>
  <div id="billy"></div>
  <button class="animate-button" data-duration="10" data-target="ghost" data-visual="fire">10 seconds</button>
  <button class="animate-button" data-duration="20" data-target="ghost" data-visual="fire">20 seconds</button>
  <button class="animate-button" data-duration="5" data-target="billy" data-visual="water">5 seconds billy</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now! Can I ask you what would you do if instead of having one ID e.g  'ghost', you'd have multiple?

Comment: I tried using document.querySelectorAll but it didn't work

Comment: I updated with a new answer, view the edit to get the OLD one (or I can post back in as a separate example if needed), note use of somewhat experimental method.  Try to click one of the first two, then the last and see them race :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a little function that takes the animation time in seconds as an argument. Read the comments in the code for explanation.

```js
function animation(duration) {
  // select whatever element you are trying to animate
  let target = document.getElementById('ghost');
  // change the animationduration before starting to animate
  target.style.animationDuration = `${duration}s`;
  // add the animating class and start the animation
  target.classList.add('animating');
  // create a timeout to remove the animating class from your animated element
  setTimeout(() => {
    target.classList.remove('animating');
  }, `${duration*1000}`);
}
```

```css
 #ghost{
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
 }
 .animating {
      animation: move 10s linear;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes move {
      from {
        left: 0%;
      }
      to {
        left: 100%;
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <div id="ghost"> </div>
  <button onclick="animation(10);">10 seconds </button>
  <button onclick="animation(20);"> 20 seconds </button>
```